# Перезагрузка страницы после нажатия на кнопку скрытия элемента

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Мне надо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `Hide`, элемент скрывался, а при нажатии на кнопку `Show`, появлялся.
У меня раньше всё работало, а сейчас вдруг перестало. При нажатии на любую из этих кнопок, страница перезагружается. Вот мой `jquery` код:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("button").click(function(){
                        $("div").toggle();
                    });
                });
    
                    $("button").click(function(){
                        $("div").fadeIn();
                        $("div").fadeIn("slow");
                        $("div").fadeIn(3000);
                    });
```

А вот `HTML` код:

```
    <body>
        <form>
        
            <button id="hide">Hide</button>
            <button id="show">Show</button>

                <div aria-expanded="true" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" class="vm--modal"
             style="left: 1px; width: 700px; height: auto; top: -400px;">
                        <div class="ctg-modal__wrapper">
                    <div class="ctg-modal__head"><span>Введите UUID предмета</span>
                        <div class="ctg-modal__close"><span class="ol-ico ol-ico--fa ol-ico--thm-times"></span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ctg-modal__body">
                        <div>Введите UUID предмета и нажмите на кнопку "Check"</div>
                        <section>
                            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto mt-20 ol-modal-buttons">
                                    <button class="ol-btn ol-w-100 ol-minw-140  ol-btn--thm-dark ol-btn--outline"><span class="">Закрыть</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto mt-20"><a href="ССЫЛКА"
                                                                         class="ol-btn ol-w-100 ol-minw-140  ol-btn--thm-dodger-green"
                                                                         target="_blank"><span class="">Check</span></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-умолчанию для элемента типа `button` установлен тип `submit`. Поэтому отправляется форма.

Решение проблемы:

- либо ставить принудительно атрибут `type=button` для тега `button`
- либо в *JS* писать `e.preventDefault()`
- либо использовать другой `html` элемент, например `div`
- либо не оборачивать всё в тег `form`. Потому что непонятно зачем он в данном случае))

Comment: Атрибут "type=button" писать в  $("button").click(function()?

Comment: @Paraphyn в html разметке

Comment: И ещё 1 вопросик. `$("button").click(function(){ `
Можно-ли менять это текст "button" и на что? Можно ли как-то вписать айди кнопки?

Comment: @Paraphyn конечно можно. Синтаксис такой же, как у любого селектора в CSS

Comment: @Paraphyn кстати, а зачем вам там тег `form`?

Comment: Я не знаю. Я его использую чтобы всё объединить. Можно сказать для красоты. И судя по вашему комментарию, так делать не стоит. Я просто новичок. Не разбираюсь

Comment: @Paraphyn тег `form` нужен только если внутри находятся элементы формы для отправки данных на сервер. В текущем случае он не нужен. Если убрать его - это сразу решит проблему. Но останется ещё одна - одинаковое событие клика на разные кнопки (показа и скрытия), поэтому к ним стоит обращаться по id

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120088/discussion-between-paraphyn-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Когда вам нужно повесить событие на элемент, используйте его id вместо имени тэга - это позволит избежать подобных ошибок

```
        $(document).on("click", "#hide", function(){
            $(".vm--modal").toggle();
        });

        $(document).on("click", "#show", function(){
            $(".vm--modal").fadeIn();
            $(".vm--modal").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".vm--modal").fadeIn(3000);
        });
```

Comment: Вставил ваш код вместо моего. Всё равно только перезагружается :(

Comment: @Paraphyn  у вас подключен js на страницу? просто на всякий случай спрашиваю

Comment: Я использую тег `script` на странице